# Trying to run a command in bash terminal using python script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a python script for the Automation of downloading python in a specific folder for a reason.

The only part of my code that for some reason doesn't work is

```
import os
path_python = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/file/Python-3.6.8")

_ = os.system("export PATH=" + path_python +":$PATH")
_ = os.system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + path_python + "/lib" + ":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
_ = os.system("which python")
```

if I type in bash terminal

```
export PATH=/home/user/Desktop/file/Python-3.6.8:$PATH  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/Desktop/file/Python-3.6.8/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and check with `which python` it works fine but I want to use these commands from within python itself.

I want to be able to run this script on any computer so I can't specify the path unless there is a way to specify a general path to the desktop without using the user.

Comment: Each call to `os.system()` starts a **new** process entirely unrelated to the last one... that process has its own new set of variables... unrelated to those in the last one.

Comment: ... and when that process ends, the variables it created and the PATH it set is lost too.